# Printing selected Div using jqprint

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqprint

I want to print selected Div(s) of my web page using **jqpring**.

i.e.

```
<div id="divToPrint1">
Content/section to be printed.
</div>

<div id="divDontPrint1">
Content/section which will not be printed.
</div>

<div id="divToPrint2">
Content/section to be printed.
</div>

<div id="divDontPrint2">
Content/section which will not be printed.
</div>
```

Objective:  out of all the Divs here, i want to print **divToPrint1** & **divToPrint2** only in one document.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$('#my_div').html($('#divToPrint1').html());
$('#my_div').append($('#divToPrint2').html());
```

Then print my_div like

```
$('#my_div').print();
```

Comment: Have you created a div called my_div..??

Comment: Oh Yes, Need to place intermediate Div element on the page, it works..Thank you!